# Mass exchange between stars

Tags: gravity, stars, stellar-physics

I'm curious, are there specific conditions for a transfer of mass between two stars as they pass near each other? Its for my final project in computing, I'm writing a gravity simulation and thought it'd be a nice touch.

Comment: I'm not an astrophysicist but I think it's most likely to happen in binary systems where one star is a red giant.  Are you familiar with the term "accretion disk" or the mechanisms for [type 1a supernova](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_Ia_supernova)?

Comment: I have never heard of either, i can google them though. I thought binary stars would be most likely too, as well as potentially with black holes, though not sure about them

Answer (score 2):

This was more a comment than an answer, but I can not comment due to lack of reputation. Stars can exchange mass either by stellar wind, or by  [Roche lobe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_lobe) overflow:
[image: overflow]

It basically depends on the separation, on the masses, and on the star type.

Comment: Thats more helpful than nothing

Comment: The related [Roche limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_limit) wiki has some formulas the OP might find useful too.

Comment: I was going to pen a new answer, but at the end of the day this is basically all there is too it, as far as conditions go. I was going to describe observed systems where this is happening, but that's not in the question. Look at references for the [Roche lobe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_lobe) and Roche lobe overflow.